# DELETE From table

Tags: mysql, delete-row

how can delete "TEST" in message field of posts_comments table

```
DELETE FROM `posts_comments` WHERE `message` LIKE `TEST`
```

i want all comments have TEST remove from posts_comments table

Comment: Replace `LIKE 'TEST'` with `LIKE '%TEST%'` ? Is this what you're after ? It's not very clear from your question...

Comment: Try **DELETE FROM `posts_comments` WHERE `message` LIKE `%TEST%`**

Comment: no i don't need replace i want remove that row completely

Comment: @user3261715, He meant replace in the code, it won't do a replace of your rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `MySQL Wildcard '%'` in order to simulate `Contains` operation.

**Code:**

```
DELETE FROM `posts_comments` WHERE `message` LIKE '%TEST%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need single quotes (not backticks) around the string constant:

```
DELETE FROM `posts_comments`
    WHERE `message` LIKE 'TEST';
```

In fact, queries are easier to read without backticks.  Only use backticks when necessary -- when using unusual characters in an identifier (anything except alpha, numeric, or underscore) or MySQL reserved words.  Then, follow the rule that you never use unusual characters in an identifier.  And never use MySQL reserved words.

```
DELETE FROM posts_comments
    WHERE message LIKE 'TEST';
```